# AutoMapping an Enum to an Entity Framework 5.0 complex type error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, automapper

So the error is this: Expression must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties.

Remuneration in the DTO is a Enum. ContractEntity uses a Remuneration that is a ComplexType.

The code throwing the error:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContractDTO, ContractEntity>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Remuneration.ContractType, s => s.MapFrom(z => z.ContractType))
            .ForMember(d => d.Remuneration.Currency, s => s.MapFrom(z => z.Currency))
            .ForMember(d => d.Remuneration.RateUnit, s => s.MapFrom(z => z.RateUnit));
```

Entity Framework complex type:

```
 [ComplexType]
public class Remuneration
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int Currency { get; set; }
    public int RateUnit { get; set; }
    public int ContractType { get; set; }    
}
```

Because I want the destination (ContractEntity) to use the integer values, I thought I could just cast the source enum to the destination integer like this:

```
.ForMember(d => d.Remuneration.ContractType, s => s.MapFrom(z => (int)z.ContractType))
```

.. obviously I cant, and was hoping that someone could clarify why this doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

If you have problmes with complex type mapping, you can implement manual mapping based on AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PatternDto, PatternModel>().ConvertUsing(pattern =>
                {
                    if(pattern == null) return new PatternModel();
                    return new PatternModel
                        {
                            EmailPattern = pattern.EmailPattern,
                            SmsPattern = pattern.SmsPattern
                        };
                });
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Andrei - tried that but the problem is that ContactEntity has a ComplexType of Remuneration which has properties that I cant access using your example. In other words: PatternModel has a complextype of MessagePatterns which have properties of EmailPattern and SMSPatterns.

Comment: And again it is possible somehow to solve your problem with ConvertUsing

Comment: Possibly, the question is how?

Comment: Tried this as well but it doesnt work:  Mapper.CreateMap<ContractType, int>().ConvertUsing(pattern => (int)pattern);
            Mapper.CreateMap<Currency, int>().ConvertUsing(pattern => (int)pattern);
            Mapper.CreateMap<RateUnit, int>().ConvertUsing(pattern => (int)pattern);